# Is there a way to source stream from query parameters with akka-http?

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I know how to source stream from an entity via a POST request, but I want to be able to also create a source stream from the query parameters of a GET request.

I know i can get query parameters to a case class via a as[] directive, but it seems like a miss to have to wrap that in a source in order to source stream it.

Answer (score 0):

The query parameters that are part of the [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) are not "streamed" from the client, rather [they are part of the request line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_format).  Therefore, when you have an `HttpRequest` object in your memory you have already consumed enough space to hold the query parameters.  This means that you lose any back-pressure benefits from using a `Source`.  I recommend analyzing why you want to create a Source in the first place...

If you absolutely have to create a Source out of the parameters then you can use the [`parameterSeq` Directive](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterSeq.html):

```
val route = 
  parameterSeq { params : Seq[(String, String)] =>

    val parameterSource : Source[(String, String), _] = Source(params)

  }
```